# How to share a Cancellation Token with two DLL?

Tags: c#, ilmerge, cancellation, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I've the following code in a **FIRST dll** :

```
public Task FuncAsync(string a, string b, CancellationToken ct)
{

    Task t = new Task
        (
            () =>
            {
                Save(a, b, ct);
            }, ct
        );

    t.Start();
    return t;
}

private void Save(string a, string b, CancellationToken ct)
{
    classA.func(a, b, ct); // DOESNT WORK !
    //classA.func(a, c);     // WORKS !
}
```

The method class `classA` is in the **SECOND dll** :

```
public void func(string a, string b, CancellationToken ct)
{
// some code...
}
public delegate void ProgressHandler(object sender, ProgressArgs progressArgs);
public event ProgressHandler ProgressChanged;
```

Then, my method FuncAsync is called in a Console Application :

```
CancellationTokenSource cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = cancelSource.Token;
Task task = B.SaveAsync("", "", ct);
```

The first DLL include the second, the console application include the first DLL.

This code compiles fine, no warning, no error. But on execution, error on the line : Save(a, b, ct);

*`Additional information: Could not load type 'ProgressHandler' from assembly 'A.B.C, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method 'func' has no implementation (no RVA).`*

If I delete the CancellationToken from the code, all is ok.

How can I send my CancellationToken from the Application to the DLL1, then from DLL1 to the DLL2 ?

**EDIT :**

I forgot to precise that I merge the two DLL in one only with the command :

```
ILMerge /target:libray dll1Temp.dll  dll2.dll  /out:dll1.dll  /internalize /allowDup /lib:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
del dll1Temp.dll
del dll2.dll
```

When I don't merge the library, there are no error in my code.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using the 'extern' keyword anywhere in your code (other than for proper DLLImport p/invoke).

Comment: This sounds weird. Do you load the second DLL dynamically and instantiate `classA` dynamically? Then: are you sure the version you're loading implements the method with the cancellation token parameter?

Comment: are any of these asp.net web sites, not asp.net web applications?

Comment: My bad, I use the extern KeyWord in the second DLL. The method func call some methods in : [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] protected static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(...)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar : The second DLL is referenced in my first DLL. The version loaded implements correctly the cancellation token parameter.

Comment: @Daniel : All my code is in C#

Comment: @Apaachee thats fine but what kind of project is it? winforms, wpf, etc?

Comment: My 2 DLL are 'Class Library' project, the application is a WPF application

Comment: I just edited my post with an important precision.